# cv2 ndarray convert to list then backward to ndarray cannot display correctly

Tags: python, opencv, numpy-ndarray

I need to transmit my video stream via JSON format, so I try to convert ndarray which read from cv2 to list first, and then backward to ndarray again to read it. Here is my code in python.

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
while(video.isOpened()):
    success, frame = video.read()
    data = frame.tolist()
    image = np.asarray(data)
    cv2.imshow('frame', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video.release()
```

However, I just got a image with all black, not the original video screen. Why and how to correct it? Thank you.

Comment: Try `image = np.asarray(data, dtype=np.uint8)`, my guess is you're converting from `uint8` to `int64` and `imshow` is interpreting the data differently.

Comment: Thanks,it works.   Can you give my some explain why this happen?

Comment: Sure, `frame.tolist()` is converting from `np.uint8` to the default python `int` type. When you convert back, numpy is interpreting that as an `int64` unless explicitly told not to.

Comment: No point in this transition --- `frame` is already a numpy array. Casting it to a list and then back to an array doesn't do anything.

Comment: Alex, I just skip the part I send it to kafka broker and read it from consumer.  Jodag's explain is great!